# Rolling data up by month per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

This is really stumping me, but maybe the answer is just hiding in plain sight and I can't see the pesky bugger. But then again, I'm no DBA and I'm trying to learn how to write more complex SQL that rolls months of records up instead of pulling thousands of records. That way I can aggregate that data on the backend to lighten the load on the clientend.

I want to select years worth of data from a database and roll up each month into its own record within a separate table. That means I should have at most, 12 records for 12 months out of the year * the amount of years I'm selecting.

This seems simple in my mind, I select a date range and case it out by month used DATEPART(MM, ). Then I use simple COUNT(), AVG() and ETC functions to roll up that data into the month outside of the case statement.

However, that's not working so well. So, how do you select a range of data, aggregate multiple columns by month into one record and go through years of data in one select statement? I can do this with one select statement summarizing one month easy, just not every month out of the year * the amount of years I want to backdate.

EXAMPLE

This code does everything I want. Just need to make this able to do the same for every month out of the year * the amount of years I want to apply.

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date='2013-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate Date='2013-02-01'

SELECT @Name, 
    @StartDate, 
    COUNT(a.[CODE]),
    SUM(a.[TICKETS]),
    AVG(a.[TICKETS]),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM [SOMETABLE] a
WHERE a.[CODE] = @Name
AND a.[DATE] >= @StartDate
AND a.[DATE] < @EndDate
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like; edited to reflect requirements to use first date of each month:

```
DECLARE @StartDate Date='2013-01-01'
DECLARE @EndDate Date='2013-02-01'

SELECT @Name, 
    DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, a.[date]),0), 
    COUNT(a.[CODE]),
    SUM(a.[TICKETS]),
    AVG(a.[TICKETS]),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END),
    COUNT(CASE WHEN a.[FLAG1] IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
FROM [SOMETABLE] a
WHERE a.[CODE] = @Name
AND a.[DATE] >= @StartDate
AND a.[DATE] < @EndDate
GROUP BY DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, a.[date]),0)
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked pretty great. I just have to fix the @StartDate where it pulls the first day of that rolled up month as opposed to putting '2013-01-01' in every record. I can handle that though.

Thanks again for pointing out the obvious with GROUP BY.

Comment: I just edited it; if it's helpful, please be sure to mark it as the correct answer.

Comment: Looks good on my end. Now, I'm just trying to understand how these functions are working in this manner. The other approach with selecting the month and year with DATEPART was pretty understandable on my end. But, thanks for the additional assistance.

Starting to like playing with data now.

Comment: You're welcome; I did a blog post on the syntax a few years ago: http://codegumbo.com/index.php/2009/07/24/you-can-teach-an-old-dog/